# Articles before abstract nouns

Tags: grammar, articles

I have a problem understanding usage of articles before abstract nouns.
There are a couple of rules I found:

- Use articles with uncountable abstract nouns to refer to a specific feeling: a deep distrust, an everlasting love, the love of music
- We only use an article before an abstract noun if we wish to talk about a specific type of the noun

Could you please explain, why the following sentences are correct (they are from a textbook):

1) `However, it ends with great optimism.` - it seems to me like a specific feeling that requires an indefinite article

2) `Would you like to experience the deep sense of satisfaction you get from creating your own original work` - why do we use `the` article before `deep sense`, not an indefinite article `a` or no article?

3) `She brought me up in relative peace and security` - why don't we need any article before `peace and security`?

4) `I was overwhelmed by the excitement of such an adventure` - why do we need `the` here?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: #1 *great* is a determiner. #2 it's a specific 'deep sense ...' (the sort "you get from ..."). #3 *relative* is a determiner. #4 it's a particular aspect of the adventure.

Comment: These articles on determiners might also be helpful: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners), [LearnEnglish](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers).

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you very much for your reply! Could you please clarify the difference of using `a` or `the` articles before abstract nouns?

Comment: @Lawrence Why `everlasting` in a phrase `an everlasting love` isn't a determiner?

Comment: This isn't directly to do with abstract nouns. // (2) and (4) include postmodification of the noun, making it specific (cf _the man I saw_; _the loss I felt_). // (1) Could use 'a', but that would be a more literary / formal style. Non-count nouns don't usually take the indefinite article.  See the duplicate. // (3) 'in peace' is a prepositional phrase, and collocation.

Comment: @Konstantin I'm not sure (try asking one of the linguists here) - maybe something to do with it being an adjective, or perhaps the phrase has 2 determiners. Have a look at the following sections in the wikipedia link: "Combinations of determiners" and "Determiners and adjectives".